# Need advice on whether PIVOT is the correct tool in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, row-number

My data looks like this:

```
| ACCNT | AMOUNT | TYPE | YEAR |
|-------|--------|------|------|
|  458  | 168.80 | A    | 2014 |
|  458  | 282.77 | A    | 2015 |
|  458  | 64.70  | B    | 2015 |
|  458  | 91.25  | A    | 2016 |
|  458  | 398.00 | B    | 2016 |
|  458  | 104.45 | C    | 2016 |
|  927  | 445.00 | B    | 2014 |
|  927  | 25.00  | A    | 2015 |
|  927  | 10.00  | NULL | 2015 |
|  927  | 132.00 | A    | 2016 |
|  927  | 381.40 | B    | 2016 |
|  927  | 210.00 | C    | 2016 |
...
```

An Accnt might not have a value for each Year, and the Type will occasionally be NULL.
I want to have just one row per Accnt, and combine the Amount & Type columns under a Year heading, i.e. to get it looking like this:

```
| ACCNT |   2014    |       2015         |           2016             |
|-------|-----------|--------------------|----------------------------|
|  458  | 168.80,A  | 282.77,A;64.70,B   | 91.25,A;398.00,B;104.45,C  |  
|  927  | 445.00,B  | 25.00,A;10.00,NULL | 132.00,A;381.40,B;210.00,C |
...
```

I can pivot on the [Year]...

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT [Accnt], [Amount], [Type], [Year] FROM data_table) 
 AS Source
PIVOT
(
 MAX([Amount]) FOR [Year] IN ([2014],[2015],[2016])
) AS PVT
```

...but still end up with multiple rows per Accnt.

The following gets closer to the format I'm looking for...

```
SELECT Accnt, [1] AS '2014', [2] AS '2015', [3] AS '2016'
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Accnt ORDER BY [Year] Asc) AS AccountID, 
Accnt, CONVERT(nvarchar,Amount) + ',' + [Type]  AS Amount_And_Type
FROM  data_table) PIVOT (MAX(Amount_And_Type) 
FOR AccountID IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS data_pvt
```

...but it's just giving me the first three rows for each Accnt:

```
| ACCNT |   2014    |   2015   |  2016   |
|-------|-----------|----------|---------|
|  458  | 168.80,A  | 282.77,A | 67.40,B |  
|  927  | 445.00,B  | 25.00,A  | NULL    |
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with a Pivot?

Comment: Ideally the presentation of data would be taken care of at the Presentation layer; not at the data layer.  That said why do databases have a pivot then?

Comment: Have a look at `stuff` and `for xml` functions for converting rows of data into single fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query as below:

```
;with cte as (
    select Accnt, iif([2014] is null,null, concat([2014],',',[Type])) as [2014a]
        ,iif([2015] is null,null, concat([2015],',',[Type])) as [2015a]
        ,iif([2016] is null,null, concat([2016],',',[Type])) as [2016a]
     from youracct
    pivot(max(amount) for [year] in ([2014],[2015],[2016])) p
) 
select c.Accnt, [2014]= stuff(( Select ';'+[2014a] from cte where Accnt = c.Accnt for xml path('')),1,1,'')    
,[2015]=stuff(( Select ';'+[2015a] from cte where Accnt = c.Accnt for xml path('')),1,1,'')  
,[2016]=stuff(( Select ';'+[2016a] from cte where Accnt = c.Accnt for xml path('')),1,1,'')  
from cte c
group by c.Accnt
```

But dynamic sql for this approach is bit complex but we can do..

Output as below:

```
+-------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
| Accnt |  2014   |      2015       |          2016          |
+-------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
|   458 | 168.8,A | 282.77,A;64.7,B | 91.25,A;398,B;104.45,C |
|   927 | 445,B   | 10,;25,A        | 132,A;381.4,B;210,C    |
+-------+---------+-----------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: `iif` and `concat` won't work in SQL Server 2008 R2, so I tried the following instead: select `Accnt, 
 case [2014] when NULL then 'NULL' else (CONVERT(nvarchar,[2014]) + ',' + [Type]) end as [2014a],...` but it leaves out the 10.00 amount with a Type of NULL.  My understanding of how this query works isn't strong enough to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: for iif you can use coalesce and instead of concat you can use +

Comment: Let me try to explain a bit... If you query the CTE alone it will get pivot for year and stuff is used to concatenate

Comment: Try running CTE alone by adding select * from CTE below the CTE you will get the inputs